# Software to schedule copying of files

Tags: windows, scheduling, copy-paste

Is there a software that can easilly schedule the copying of a few files to another location ?

It must allow to create a list of files and specify destination.
(I saw Drop It but from a quick look at it it can only auto-scan folders and copy based on filter, and not create a list..)

Comment: This is likely doable with Task Scheduler (to, well, schedule the task) and a batch file (to do the copying).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for my employer who might not have time to setup batch files etc. But I just tested and Drop It can actually do it, it just wasn't user friendly enough so it took me some time